# Google Sheets, Sorting not working as intended due to some unknown reason

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter

I'm currently doing a spreadsheet to record form responses from google forms and then I'm moving the data through queries into a separate sheet for clarity. As you can see from the link below, My data moves over perfectly although if I try and sort the range (Z-A) based on the C column ("Taglia").
The sorting just goes wrong and the data ends up all over the place for no reason. It is due to the formula i put in the C column which essentially gathers information from the spreadsheet "Form Responses 1"?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b3bhyU8sOc-AWAx3XXRBzmRTkzYUaYtmXSHct6Xk4nY/edit#gid=1469984416

Comment: how do you perform that sorting?

Comment: I sort by highlighting the table and then using advanced sorting to exlucde the first row as header and then i sort by coloumn C (Taglia) Z-A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete all your formulae and try in A2:

```
=QUERY({'Form responses 1'!B2:C100, 
 BYROW('Form responses 1'!D2:AN100, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 FILTER(x, REGEXMATCH('Form responses 1'!D1:AN1, "Taglia"))))),
 BYROW('Form responses 1'!D2:AN100, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 FILTER(x, NOT(REGEXMATCH('Form responses 1'!D1:AN1, "Taglia")))))),
 'Form responses 1'!AO2:AV100}, "where Col1 is not null order by Col3 asc", )
```

[image]

---

### update:

delete everything and use this in A1:

```
={SPLIT(" ×Nominativo×Modello×Taglia×Colore Abbigliamento×Colore Serigrafia×Tipo di Spedizione×Nome e Cognome×Indirizzo e Numero Civico×Cap×Città×Nazione×Numero Di Cellulare", "×"); 
 INDEX(QUERY({IFERROR('Form responses 1'!B2:B100/0), 'Form responses 1'!B2:C100, 
 BYROW('Form responses 1'!D2:AN100, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 FILTER(x, REGEXMATCH('Form responses 1'!D1:AN1, "Taglia"))))), 
 BYROW('Form responses 1'!D2:AN100, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 FILTER(x, NOT(REGEXMATCH('Form responses 1'!D1:AN1, "Taglia")))))), 
 'Form responses 1'!AO2:AV100}, "where Col2 is not null", ))}
```

then create a filter:

[image]

and make sure A1 is not included:

[image]

now you can sort it as you wish

Comment: Unfortunatly when i sort by Coloumn C "Taglia" unfortunatly It doesn't sort and gives me 2 empty rows at the top.

Comment: @AlbyMagno answer updated

Comment: Works perfectly. Is there any reason why the sorting only works when using filter views rather than traditional filtering ? Also if you have the time could you explain why your answer works compared to mine? Thank you very much

Comment: @AlbyMagno think of this filter approach as something like an overlay or layer where with it you can sort it freely but under it the dataset is not changed anyhow. also, keep in mind that formula is not static. they are constantly up to date so that's the reason why formula needs to be outside the filtered range so the change from filter sorting would not trigger a forced recalculation